# Get data from self-referencing table in all directions

Tags: sql, oracle, self-reference

I have a table with such rows:

```
    ID        Parent_ID   Name
    1         (null)      A
    2         1           B
    3         1           C
    4         2           D
    5         3           E
    6         5           F
    7         (null)      G
    8         (null)      H
```

I need to get IDs of all related rows no matter if Name='A' or 'F' is passed as criteria. In this case I should receive all ID beside 7 and 8.

I tried lot of examples and read a lot of articles but I give up now. Can you help with it?

Comment: Do you mean `WHEN Parent_ID IS NOT NULL` or is there a deeper logic?  Please spell out the exact meaning of "*related rows*".

Comment: You say the table is "self referencing": please give us details of the foreign keys.

Comment: please explain question properly.

Comment: apparently your table represents a tree - correct? does 'related' mean 1. part of the same tree, 2. a descendant 3. an ancestor 4. some combination of the beforementioned 5. something entirely different? enough second-guessing ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with
   t as (
      select id
      from your_table
      where name = 'D'  -- your starting point
   )
select id
from (
   select id, parent_id from your_table
   where parent_id is not null
   union all
   select parent_id, id from your_table
   where parent_id is not null
   union all
   select id, null from t
)
start with parent_id is null
connect by nocycle prior id = parent_id
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6e1d3/1)

Answer (score 0):

`A` is at the root of a hierarchy (it's the parent of `B`, which is the parent of `D`, etc.). To start with `A` and work down to `F` (and also down to `D` and `E`, which also have `A` as a parent through different routes):

```
SELECT ID, Parent_ID, Name
FROM tbl
START WITH Name = 'A'
CONNECT BY PRIOR ID = Parent_ID
```

`F` is at the end of a hierarchy. Oracle calls this a "leaf". To start with leaf `F` and work up to `A` at the top:

```
SELECT ID, Parent_ID, Name
FROM tbl
START WITH Name = 'F' -- start with F instead of A
CONNECT BY PRIOR Parent_ID = ID -- switch the CONNECT BY to work up
```

Oracle has a `SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH` function that's great for visualizing the hierarchy. Here's how to use it in the first query (`A` down to `F`):

```
SELECT ID, Parent_ID, Name, SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(Name, '/') AS Path
FROM tbl
START WITH Name = 'A'
CONNECT BY PRIOR ID = Parent_ID
```

Results:

```
  ID  PARENT_ID NAME PATH
---- ---------- ---- -----------
   1            A    /A
   2          1 B    /A/B
   4          2 D    /A/B/D
   3          1 C    /A/C
   5          3 E    /A/C/E
   6          5 F    /A/C/E/F
```

You can use any delimeter you want as the second argument to `SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH`.